# Did Captain America ever come face-to-face with Hitler?

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america

Hitler has appeared several times on the cover of *Captain America Comics* (1941). For example, on the cover of the first issue,

[image]

you can see Captain America punching Hitler. But, Hitler wasn't there in the story of that issue.

Did Captain America ever come face-to-face with (or really punched) Hitler in the story of entire comics?

Comment: Are we counting clones, like the Hate-Monger?

Comment: @Adamant No. Of course, he isn't real Hitler.

Comment: Weird cover to use for an issue that doesn't feature Hitler. "Smashing thru, Captain America came face to face with Hitler"

Comment: How about butt-to-face?

Comment: Well, Cap's knocked out Adolf more than 200 times, so....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Yes—and more than once!

In *Tales of Suspense* #67 (1965), Captain America is temporarily brainwashed and brought before the the Führer:

[image: Red Skull brings a brainwashed Captain America before Hitler]

### And he did (sort of) fight him

As shown in *Captain America Comics #2* ("Trapped in the Nazi Stronghold"), where we see two Nazis called Hermann and Adolph (obviously meant to be *Hermann Göring* and *Adolf Hitler*):

[image: Bucky defeats Hermann and Adolph]

Admittedly, Bucky is doing the actual fighting, but it’s pretty close (and another example of Cap meeting Hitler face-to-face).

Some of the many other times Hitler met Captain America are listed on the [former’s page on the Marvel wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Adolf_Hitler_(Earth-616)/Expanded_History), including bonus appearances from the [Hate-Monger](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hate-Monger_(Earth-616)) (a clone of Hitler).

Comment: Hitler wasn't there in Captain America Comics #2. The comic panel you added doesn't have Hitler in it whether one looks like him or not.

Comment: @ILoveYou - Sorry, what? Adolph and Hermann? Not sure what you mean: they’re obviously supposed to be Hitler and Goering. Look, you can even see the mustache in the third panel.

Comment: From the description on the wiki, too: “Travelling there, the two heroes storm the camp and free Baldwin, delivering a humiliating defeat to the Nazis while Hitler and Hermann Goering are both on location.” All the other sources I found talked about Bucky kicking Hitler, too.

Comment: Adolph is just a regular soldier. The correct spelling of Hitler's first name is Adolf. Wiki is wrong.

Comment: @ILoveYou - It’s a *mistake*. The writer didn’t know how to spell his name properly. That doesn’t mean he’s not Hitler.

Comment: That fight scene happened in America and over a cheap thing. Common sense would say that he wasn't Hitler. Read that comic right away: http://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Captain-America-Comics/Issue-2?id=37362

Comment: @ILoveYou - Umm what, in *America*? It’s in Germany. What gave you the idea that it was in the US?

Comment: At that point, Captain America was dealing with German spies in America. He had never visited Germany. Read that issue: http://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Captain-America-Comics/Issue-2?id=37362

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58942/discussion-between-adamant-and-i-love-you).

Comment: I have two thoughts.  1) That's some high quality Germanglish in the first page there.  2) "Boys, you can both have me" is probably the naughtiest thing ever said in a Captain America comic.

Comment: Also, "skull" in German is "Totenkopf," which can be loosely glossed as "dead head," making this charming crimson fellow "Red Dead Head," and that makes me laugh.

Comment: @Paul let's not forget the "Are you both satisfied?" line from the next panel.